CSP inline issue nonce
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'nonce-Vs0RA4diyTa6WTnfA4Cy3Q=='". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-DCi8t3r+YRqVUj7mwqQSCiWFl6zZOX7K41Xi0fvwscs='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution
how to resolve this issue
const crypto = require('crypto');
const nonce = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64');
res.header("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate");
res.setHeader(
'Content-Security-Policy', default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'nonce-${nonce}'; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; frame-src 'self');
currently I am doing this

Due to lack information, I'll have to resort to some guessing/guidance that hopefully might lead you in the right direction:
You show an error for blocked style, while you are showing a script. This script doesn't insert styles, so it is likely unrelated to the error you have shown.
You have successfully added a nonce. Is this nonce shown in the inline style? Remember that only style tags are nonceable, style attributes are not. If it is a style attribute you should rewrite it with a classname and style in a separate file. Otherwise you'll likely need to use a hash and 'unsafe-hashes'.
